# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a mi página web Python desde otro PC?

Tags: python, web, servidor, localhost, host

tengo un proyecto en Python, en mi computador, la ruta es , `G:/programacion/python/proyectos/cienciex`

Y quiero poder acceder a mi local host desde cualquier equipo dentro de la red local

El proyecto se encuentra hecho en Django, el servidor se ejecuta en el puerto 8000, así que accedo a él en el ordenador con la dirección: `localhost:8000`
Lo ejecuto con el comando `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Y cómo está hecho ese proyecto? Cómo lo ejecutas? En qué framework está hecho? Cómo está configurado? Qué probaste para hacer que esto pase? Cómo falló? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: puedes usar `ngrok` que permite levantar un servidor con protocolos http y https. Además se puede acceder desde cualquier parte y no solo en tu red local.

Comment: Por definición `"localhost"` no es accesible desde fuera. Es un nombre que se resuelve a la misma máquina en la que lo uses (normalmente a la IP 127.0.0.1 que solo es accesible desde esa misma máquina). Ocurre que cuando lanzas django por defecto éste hace un bind a la IP 127.0.0.1, lo que hace que solo acepte peticiones que vengan de esa misma máquina. Si lo lanzas de modo que haga el bind a la IP 0.0.0.0, eso hará que acepte peticiones desde cualquier interfaz de red. Así podrás desde otra máquina conectar (poniendo la IP del servidor)

Comment: Es posible que en el momento que Django intente hacer el bind a 0.0.0.0 (como explicaba en mi anterior comentario), el Cortafuegos de Windows te salte y te pida permiso. Debes decirle que permita a python escuchar en el puerto 8000 (de lo contrario el cortafuegos impedirá conexiones entrantes desde otros equipos)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que acceder a través de la dirección IP de tu la computadora en donde está corriendo tu proyecto:

Por ejemplo:

```
192.168.1.29:8000
```

Comment: A esto, le añadiría revisar el firewall del equipo donde corre para que permita esas conexiones entrantes al puerto 8000, por ejemplo

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: @rpaillao, yo por lo menos no veo por que esta respuesta se parece a un comentario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude

Answer (score 0):

Debes correr el servidor en tu pc local con

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

o

```
python manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

después obtienes la ip de tu equipo entrando a propiedades del sistemas (redes e internet) o ejecutando `ipconfig/all` en cmd. Eso te debe arrojar algo parecido a esto:
*192.168.0.15*, y esto es lo que debes escribir en el navegador de los otros computadores de tu red local junto con el puerto:

```
192.168.0.15:8000
```

Answer (score -1):

En teoría si quieres acceder desde una red local puedes usar

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Despues miras la ip local de tu maquina y te conectas

Mas informacion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido

Comment: dale que esta es la respuesta porfa @JavierVergara